# Amcharts - not able to load external Json data

Tags: json, amcharts, amcharts4, external-data-source

I'm trying to load external json data into regular amcharts line chart. If I paste exactly same Json data into **chart.data** property it works perfectly. But when I use **chart.dataSource.url** property and call the page with same json data, its not working.

**SNIPPET WITH DATA INSIDE JAVASCRIPT - WORKING**

```js
var chart
var valueAxis
var valueAxisAll


// Create chart instance
    chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Increase contrast by taking evey second color
    //chart.colors.step = 2;

// Create Category axes
    // var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
     var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
     /*
     categoryAxis.baseInterval = {
      timeUnit: "day",
      count: 1
    };
    */

    //categoryAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true; 
 
    // categoryAxis.dataFields.category = headers[0];

    //categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -45;
    //categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";


// Create Value axis series
    valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    
//create series
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    //set x & y
    series.dataFields.valueY ="value";
    series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series.name = "Rýchlost v km/h";
    
    //series.fillOpacity = 0.3;
    series.strokeWidth = 2;
    series.stroke = "#4484CE";
    series.tensionX = 1; //smoothen between 0 & 1
    series.yAxis = valueAxis;
    var myBullets = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    myBullets.hideBulletsCount= 10;
    series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    series.minBulletDistance = 25;

    series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
    series.tooltip.autoTextColor = false;
    series.tooltip.label.fill = "#3f4652";
    series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
    series.tooltip.fillOpacity = 1.0;
    series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 1.0;
   

    //valueAxis settings
    //valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
    //valueAxis.renderer.line.stroke = series.stroke;
    //valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = series.stroke;
    valueAxis.renderer.opposite = false;
    //valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;

    var gradient = new am4core.LinearGradient();
    gradient.addColor(am4core.color("green"));
    gradient.addColor(am4core.color("yellow"));
    gradient.addColor(am4core.color("red"));
    gradient.rotation = 270;
    //rect.fill = gradient;

    var range = valueAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
    range.value = 0;
    range.endValue = 100;
    range.contents.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(1);
    range.contents.fill = gradient;
    range.contents.fillOpacity = 0.4;



chart.data = [{"date":"2020-07-27 15:27:10","value":14.3},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:28:10","value":12.5},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:29:10","value":13.9},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:30:10","value":8.6},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:31:10","value":5.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 16:27:11","value":12.9},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:27:11","value":17.6},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:35:11","value":15.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:45:11","value":19.2},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:58:11","value":22.5},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:28:23","value":20.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:38:23","value":18.6},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:40:23","value":24.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:55:23","value":25.9},
{"date":"2020-07-28 10:28:23","value":33.8},
{"date":"2020-07-28 10:35:59","value":30.4},
{"date":"2020-07-28 10:45:59","value":28.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 15:56:59","value":35.9},
{"date":"2020-07-28 15:58:59","value":37.5},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:00:59","value":24.2},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:27:48","value":32.4},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:35:48","value":35.2},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:42:48","value":39.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:45:48","value":40.3},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:48:48","value":40.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:50:12","value":39.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:51:12","value":35.7},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:52:12","value":28.5},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:53:12","value":22.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:54:12","value":15.6},
];
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 90%; height: 300px" ;></div>
```

**SNIPPET WITH EXTERNAL JSON DATA LOAD - NOT WORKING**

```js
var chart
var valueAxis
var valueAxisAll


// Create chart instance
    chart = am4core.create("chartdiv_wind", am4charts.XYChart);

// Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Increase contrast by taking evey second color
    //chart.colors.step = 2;

// Create Category axes
    // var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
     var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
     /*
     categoryAxis.baseInterval = {
      timeUnit: "day",
      count: 1
    };
    */

    //categoryAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true; 
 
    // categoryAxis.dataFields.category = headers[0];

    //categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = -45;
    //categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";


// Create Value axis series
    valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    
//create series
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    //set x & y
    series.dataFields.valueY ="value";
    series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series.name = "Rýchlost v km/h";
    
    //series.fillOpacity = 0.3;
    series.strokeWidth = 2;
    series.stroke = "#4484CE";
    series.tensionX = 1; //smoothen between 0 & 1
    series.yAxis = valueAxis;
    var myBullets = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    myBullets.hideBulletsCount= 10;
    series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    series.minBulletDistance = 25;

    series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
    series.tooltip.autoTextColor = false;
    series.tooltip.label.fill = "#3f4652";
    series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
    series.tooltip.fillOpacity = 1.0;
    series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 1.0;
   

    //valueAxis settings
    //valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
    //valueAxis.renderer.line.stroke = series.stroke;
    //valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = series.stroke;
    valueAxis.renderer.opposite = false;
    //valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
    valueAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;

    var gradient = new am4core.LinearGradient();
    gradient.addColor(am4core.color("green"));
    gradient.addColor(am4core.color("yellow"));
    gradient.addColor(am4core.color("red"));
    gradient.rotation = 270;
    //rect.fill = gradient;

    var range = valueAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
    range.value = 0;
    range.endValue = 100;
    range.contents.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(1);
    range.contents.fill = gradient;
    range.contents.fillOpacity = 0.4;

  
chart.dataSource.url = "datatemp.asp?co=5";
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
chart.dataSource.parser.options.emptyAs = 0;
chart.dataSource.reloadFrequency = 10000;
chart.dataSource.incremental = true;
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

```html
    <script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
    <div id="chartdiv_wind" style="width: 90%; height: 300px" ;></div>
```

Here is a sample data from datatemp.asp?co=5

```
[{"date":"2020-07-27 15:27:10","value":14.3},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:28:10","value":12.5},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:29:10","value":13.9},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:30:10","value":8.6},
{"date":"2020-07-27 15:31:10","value":5.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 16:27:11","value":12.9},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:27:11","value":17.6},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:35:11","value":15.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:45:11","value":19.2},
{"date":"2020-07-27 17:58:11","value":22.5},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:28:23","value":20.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:38:23","value":18.6},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:40:23","value":24.8},
{"date":"2020-07-27 18:55:23","value":25.9},
{"date":"2020-07-28 10:28:23","value":33.8},
{"date":"2020-07-28 10:35:59","value":30.4},
{"date":"2020-07-28 10:45:59","value":28.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 15:56:59","value":35.9},
{"date":"2020-07-28 15:58:59","value":37.5},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:00:59","value":24.2},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:27:48","value":32.4},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:35:48","value":35.2},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:42:48","value":39.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:45:48","value":40.3},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:48:48","value":40.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:50:12","value":39.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:51:12","value":35.7},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:52:12","value":28.5},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:53:12","value":22.6},
{"date":"2020-07-28 16:54:12","value":15.6},
];
```

**Thank you for your help!!!**

Comment: Is the datatemp.asp file also sending the semicolon? If so, you should remove it, as well as the comma after the last item in the array, as both will cause your JSON to be invalid.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Appreciate your help!